# Mocking Dapper QueryAsync always return an empty list

Tags: sql, .net, mocking, moq, dapper

Trying to mock a dapper call to QueryAsync, but it always returns an empty list. Anybody know how to solve this?

```
var connection = new Mock<DbConnection>();
var input = new List<ClerkItem> { new ClerkItem(), new ClerkItem(), new ClerkItem() };
var expected = new[] { input };
connection
    .SetupDapperAsync(c => c.QueryAsync<IEnumerable<ClerkItem>>(It.IsAny<string>(), null, null, null, null))
    .ReturnsAsync(expected);

var result = await connection.Object.QueryAsync<ClerkItem>(
    "SELECT * FROM Clerk WHERE Location=@Location", 
    new { Location = "0000" }
);
var output = result.ToList();
Assert.Equal(output.Count, input.Count);
```

In this Fiddle, see the output Name is blank and not the expected input Name Joseph

https://dotnetfiddle.net/YUrsIK

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.

1. Your variable `expected` is an array of one element containing a List of three ClerkItems, you probably want to return a List of ClerkItems, so set it up like this:

```cs
var expected = new List<ClerkItem> { new ClerkItem(), new ClerkItem(), new ClerkItem() };
```

2. QueryAsync takes a model class, not an IEnumerable of model class.

The setup should be done like this:

```cs
connection
    .SetupDapperAsync(c => c.QueryAsync<ClerkItem>(It.IsAny<string>(), null, null, null, null))
    .ReturnsAsync(expected);
```

This makes the test pass, which leads me to the most important thing:

3. You aren't testing anything. This test runs nothing but test-code and has no value. If you think it has some value try to change the query to this:

```cs
var result = await connection.Object.QueryAsync<ClerkItem>(
    "HOWDY PARTNER", 
    new { Thingy = "Elephant" }
);
```

and see that it still passes. You are not alone, many programmers write tests like this. It gives a lot of little green check marks, but not much else. [Jim Coplien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Coplien) wrote a nice paper about why a lot of unit testing is a waste [here](https://rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

one way is to wrap Dapper calls in a repository class, then add an interface to that and then mocking the interface. you should have integration-test for the real Dapper calls as its not something that is scope of unit test I think.